# Python Optimized Comparison Between List of Dict

Tags: python, optimization, comparison

I'm trying to see whether nodes reside within the volume of a sphere, and add the node id to a list. However, the efficiency of the algorithm is incredibly slow and I'm not sure how to improve it.

I have two lists. List A has the format **[{'num': ID, 'x': VALUE, 'y': VALUE, 'z': VALUE]** while List B has the format **[{'x': VALUE, 'y': VALUE, 'z': VALUE, 'rad': VALUE}]**.

The size of both lists can run upwards of 100,000 items each.

My current code is posted below, but it's very inefficient.

```
    filteredList = []
    for i in range(len(sList)):

            minx = (sList[i]['x']) - (sList[i]['radius'])
            maxx = (sList[i]['x']) + (sList[i]['radius'])
            miny = (sList[i]['y']) - (sList[i]['radius'])
            maxy = (sList[i]['y']) + (sList[i]['radius'])
            minz = (sList[i]['z']) - (sList[i]['radius'])
            maxz = (sList[i]['z']) + (sList[i]['radius'])

            for j in range(len(nList)):
                    if minx <= nList[j]['x'] <= maxx:
                            if miny <= nList[j]['y'] <= maxy:
                                    if minz <= nList[j]['z'] <= maxz:
                                            tmpRad = findRadius(sList[i],nList[j])
                                            if tmpRad <= sList[i]['radius']:
                                                    filteredList.append(int(nList[j]['num']))
```

I'm at a loss and appreciate any ideas.

**Edit:** Adding extra information about the data format.

**List A** (nList) -- defines nodes, with locations x,y,z, and identifier num
[{'y': 0.0, 'x': 0.0, 'num': 1.0, 'z': 0.0},
{'y': 0.0, 'x': 1.0, 'num': 2.0, 'z': 0.0},
{'y': 0.0, 'x': 2.0, 'num': 3.0, 'z': 0.0},
{'y': 0.0, 'x': 3.0, 'num': 4.0, 'z': 0.0},
{'y': 0.0, 'x': 4.0, 'num': 5.0, 'z': 0.0},
{'y': 0.0, 'x': 5.0, 'num': 6.0, 'z': 0.0},
{'y': 0.0, 'x': 6.0, 'num': 7.0, 'z': 0.0},
{'y': 0.0, 'x': 7.0, 'num': 8.0, 'z': 0.0},
{'y': 0.0, 'x': 8.0, 'num': 9.0, 'z': 0.0},
{'y': 0.0, 'x': 9.0, 'num': 10.0, 'z': 0.0}]

**List B** (sList) -- defines spheres using x,y,z, radius
[{'y': 18.0, 'x': 25.0, 'z': 26.0, 'radius': 0.0056470000000000001},
{'y': 29.0, 'x': 23.0, 'z': 45.0, 'radius': 0.0066280000000000002},
{'y': 46.0, 'x': 29.0, 'z': 13.0, 'radius': 0.014350999999999999},
{'y': 0.0, 'x': 20.0, 'z': 25.0, 'radius': 0.014866000000000001},
{'y': 27.0, 'x': 31.0, 'z': 18.0, 'radius': 0.018311999999999998},
{'y': 10.0, 'x': 36.0, 'z': 46.0, 'radius': 0.024702000000000002},
{'y': 27.0, 'x': 13.0, 'z': 48.0, 'radius': 0.027300999999999999},
{'y': 14.0, 'x': 1.0, 'z': 13.0, 'radius': 0.033889000000000002},
{'y': 31.0, 'x': 20.0, 'z': 11.0, 'radius': 0.034118999999999997},
{'y': 23.0, 'x': 28.0, 'z': 8.0, 'radius': 0.036683}]

Comment: It would be helpful if you'd provide a few actual data points for sList and nList, rather than a description of "List A" and "List B". And what do these lists signify?

Comment: [{'num': ID} {'x': VALUE}, {'y': VALUE}, {'z': VALUE}]: Is this right? Because is seems not all dict has key x so sList[i]['x'] will throw an error.

Comment: yes he probably meant `[{'num':ID, 'x':VALUE, 'y':VALUE, 'z':VALUE}]`

Comment: Added some extra information for clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking in all this advice, I managed to come up with a solution that was about 50x faster than the original.

I realized that the bottleneck was in the datatype (list of dicts) I was using. Looping over multiple lists was incredibly slow in my cast and using sets was much more efficient.

First thing I did was to implement named tuples. I knew how my list of nodes was numbered which provided the hash I needed for efficiency.

```
def findNodesInSpheres(sList,nList,nx,ny,nz):
    print "Running findNodesInSpheres"
    filteredList = []
    for a in sList:
            rad = a.radius
            minx = (a.x) - (rad) if (a.x - rad > 0) else 0
            maxx = (a.x) + (rad) if (a.x + rad < nx ) else nx
            miny = (a.y) - (rad) if (a.y - rad > 0) else 0
            maxy = (a.y) + (rad) if (a.y + rad < ny ) else ny
            minz = (a.z) - (rad) if (a.z - rad > 0) else 0
            maxz = (a.z) + (rad) if (a.z + rad < nz ) else nz
            boundingBox = set([ (i + j * (nx + 1) + k * (nx + 1) * (ny + 1)) for i in range (int(minx),int(maxx)+1)
                            for j in range (int(miny),int(maxy)+1) for k in range(int(minz),int(maxz)+1) ])

            for b in sorted(boundingBox):
                    if findRadius(a,nList[b]) <= rad:
                            filteredList.append(nList[b].num)
    return filteredList
```

Using set() instead of list provided massive speedups. The larger the data set (nx, ny, nz), the more the speedup.

It could still be improved using tree implementation and domain decomposition as has been suggested, but for the moment it works.

Thanks to everyone for the advice!

Answer (score 3):

(This answer deals with simple optimisations and Python style; it works with the existing algorithm, teaching some points of optimisation, rather than replacing it with a more efficient one.)

Here are some points to start with to make the code easier to read and understand:

- Iterate over sList, not over range(len(sList)). `for i in range(len(sList))` becomes `for i in sList` and `sList[i]` becomes `i`.
- No need for that tmpRad; put it inline.
- Instead of `if a: if b: if c:` use `if a and b and c`.

Now we're at this:

```
filteredList = []
for i in sList:
    minx = i['x'] - i['radius']
    maxx = i['x'] + i['radius']
    miny = i['y'] - i['radius']
    maxy = i['y'] + i['radius']
    minz = i['z'] - i['radius']
    maxz = i['z'] + i['radius']

    for j in nList:
        if minx <= j['x'] <= maxx and miny <= j['y'] <= maxy and minz <= j['z'] <= maxz and findRadius(i,j) <= i['radius']:
            filteredList.append(int(j['num']))
```

(PEP 8 would recommend splitting that long line to lines of no more than 80 characters; PEP 8 would also recommend `filtered_list` and `s_list` and `n_list` rather than `filteredList`, `sList` and `nList`.)

---

I've put the `findRadius(i, j) <= i['radius']` first for style and because it looks like it might be more likely to evaluate to false, speeding up calculations. Then I've also inlined the `minx` etc. variables:

```
filteredList = []
for i in sList:
    for j in nList:
        if findRadius(i, j) <= i['radius'] \
        and i['x'] - i['radius'] <= j['x'] <= i['x'] + i['radius'] \
        and i['y'] - i['radius'] <= j['y'] <= i['y'] + i['radius'] \
        and i['z'] - i['radius'] <= j['z'] <= i['z'] + i['radius']:
            filteredList.append(int(j['num']))
```

One thing to think about is that `i['x'] - i['radius'] <= j['x'] <= i['x'] + i['radius']` could be simplified; try things like subtracting `i['x']` from all three parts.

You can shorten this even more with a list comprehension.

```
filteredList = [int(j['num']) for j in nList for i in sList
        if findRadius(i, j) <= i['radius']
        and i['x'] - i['radius'] <= j['x'] <= i['x'] + i['radius']
        and i['y'] - i['radius'] <= j['y'] <= i['y'] + i['radius']
        and i['z'] - i['radius'] <= j['z'] <= i['z'] + i['radius']]
```

And finally, [named tuples](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) (this has the side-effect of making them immutable, too, which is probably desired? Also note it's Python 2.6 only, read the page for how you could do it with older versions of Python):

```
from collections import namedtuple

node = namedtuple('node', 'x y z num')
sphere = namedtuple('sphere', 'x y z radius')

nList = [
        node(x=0.0, y=0.0, z=0.0, num=1.0),
        node(x=1.0, y=0.0, z=0.0, num=2.0),
        node(x=2.0, y=0.0, z=0.0, num=3.0),
        node(x=3.0, y=0.0, z=0.0, num=4.0),
        node(x=4.0, y=0.0, z=0.0, num=5.0),
        node(x=5.0, y=0.0, z=0.0, num=6.0),
        node(x=6.0, y=0.0, z=0.0, num=7.0),
        node(x=7.0, y=0.0, z=0.0, num=8.0),
        node(x=8.0, y=0.0, z=0.0, num=9.0),
        node(x=9.0, y=0.0, z=0.0, num=10.0)]

sList = [
        sphere(x=25.0, y=18.0, z=26.0, radius=0.0056470000000000001),
        sphere(x=23.0, y=29.0, z=45.0, radius=0.0066280000000000002),
        sphere(x=29.0, y=46.0, z=13.0, radius=0.014350999999999999),
        sphere(x=20.0, y=0.0, z=25.0, radius=0.014866000000000001),
        sphere(x=31.0, y=27.0, z=18.0, radius=0.018311999999999998),
        sphere(x=36.0, y=10.0, z=46.0, radius=0.024702000000000002),
        sphere(x=13.0, y=27.0, z=48.0, radius=0.027300999999999999),
        sphere(x=1.0, y=14.0, z=13.0, radius=0.033889000000000002),
        sphere(x=20.0, y=31.0, z=11.0, radius=0.034118999999999997),
        sphere(x=28.0, y=23.0, z=8.0, radius=0.036683)]
```

Then, instead of `sphere['radius']` you can do `sphere.radius`. This makes the code neater:

```
filteredList = [int(j.num) for j in nList for i in sList
        if findRadius(i, j) <= i.radius
        and i.x - i.radius <= j.x <= i.x + i.radius
        and i.y - i.radius <= j.y <= i.y + i.radius
        and i.z - i.radius <= j.z <= i.z + i.radius]
```

Or, without the list comprehension,

```
filteredList = []
for i in sList:
    for j in nList:
        if findRadius(i, j) <= i.radius \
        and i.x - i.radius <= j.x <= i.x + i.radius \
        and i.y - i.radius <= j.y <= i.y + i.radius \
        and i.z - i.radius <= j.z <= i.z + i.radius:
            filteredList.append(int(j.num))
```

Finally, choose nicer names; [style changed slightly as per comments, putting `findRadius` at the end as it's more likely to be computationally expensive - you're the best judge of that, though]

```
filteredList = [int(n.num) for n in nodes for s in spheres
        if s.x - s.radius <= n.x <= s.x + s.radius and
            s.y - s.radius <= n.y <= s.y + s.radius and
            s.z - s.radius <= n.z <= s.z + s.radius and
            findRadius(s, n) <= s.radius]
```

Or,

```
filteredList = []
for s in spheres:
    for n in nodes:
        if (s.x - s.radius <= n.x <= s.x + s.radius and
            s.y - s.radius <= n.y <= s.y + s.radius and
            s.z - s.radius <= n.z <= s.z + s.radius and
            findRadius(s, n) <= s.radius):
            filteredList.append(int(n.num))
```

(You could put `srad = s.radius` in the outer loop for a probable slight performance gain if desired.)

Comment: indeed namedtuple is pretty usefully. Using it might have performance improved.

Comment: Appreciate all the input you've provided. Going to implement and see what speedups there are.

Comment: I love namedtuples for this stuff, good idea.  Moving the max and min calculations and attribute lookups into the innermost loop may be a mistake for performance.  findRadius is likely more expensive then the min/max comparisons and maybe should be the last thing checked.

Comment: Agree, check findRadius last, as a) it is a function call, and b) it probably does an expensive square root calculation (I'm thinking a better name might be findDistanceFromCenter).  Also, please wrap this multiline if in ()'s and get rid of those ugly backslashes.

Comment: @Paul: final code updated in line with those (and following PEP 8 a tad more with sticking the `and` at the end).

Answer (score 1):

one we can remove from the sample

unless you need to iterate over a list by index, one shouldn't, also avoid using range, and merge ifs together

```
filteredList = []
for a in sList:

        minx = (a['x']) - (a['radius'])
        maxx = (a['x']) + (a['radius'])
        miny = (a['y']) - (a['radius'])
        maxy = (a['y']) + (a['radius'])
        minz = (a['z']) - (a['radius'])
        maxz = (a['z']) + (a['radius'])

        for b in nList:
                if minx <= b['x'] <= maxx and miny <= b['y'] <= maxy and minz <= b['z'] <= maxz:
                    tmpRad = findRadius(a,b)
                    if tmpRad <= a['radius']:
                        filteredList.append(int(b['num']))
```

Comment: a['radius'] could be set to a local variable as it is looked up many many times.

Comment: yes i thought about that but as it's mostly referenced in the outer loop and once per the inner, it didn't seem worth it

Answer (score 1):

First off, Python isn't built for that kind of iteration. Using indices to get at each element of a list is backwards, a kind of brain-damage that's taught by low-level languages where it's faster. In Python it's actually slower. `range(len(whatever))` actually creates a new list of numbers, and then you work with the numbers that are handed to you from that list. What you really want to do is *just work with objects that are handed to you from `whatever`*.

While we're at it, we can pull out the common `s['radius']` bit that is checked several times, and put all the if-checks for the bounding box on one line. Oh, and we don't need a separate 'tmpRad', and I assume the 'num's are already `int`s and don't need to be converted (if they do, why? Why not just have them converted ahead of time?)

None of this will make a **huge** difference, but it at least makes it easier to read, and definitely doesn't hurt.

```
filteredList = []
for s in sList:
  radius = s['radius']
  minx = s['x'] - radius
  maxx = s['x'] + radius
  miny = s['y'] - radius
  maxy = s['y'] + radius
  minz = s['z'] - radius
  maxz = s['z'] + radius

  for n in nList:
    if (minx <= n['x'] <= maxx) and (miny <= n['y'] <= maxy) and \
       (minz <= n['z'] <= maxz) and (findRadius(s, n) <= radius): 
      filteredList.append(n['num'])
```

Now it's at least clear what's going on.

However, for the scale of the problem we're working with, it sounds like we're going to need algorithmic improvements. What you probably want to do here is use some kind of BSP (binary space partitioning) technique. The way this works is:

- First, we rearrange the nList into a tree. We cut it up into 8 smaller lists, based on whether x > 0, whether y > 0 and whether z > 0 for each point (8 combinations of the 3 boolean results). Then each of those gets cut into 8 again, using the same sort of criteria - e.g. if the possible range for x/y/z is -10..10, then we cut the "x > 0, y > 0, z > 0" list up according to whether x > 5, y > 5, z > 5, etc. You get the idea.
- For each point in the sList, we check whether minx > 0, etc. The beautiful part: if minx > 0, we don't have to check any of the 'x < 0' lists, and if maxx < 0, we don't have to check any of the 'x > 0' lists. And so forth. We figure out which of the 8 "octants" of the space the bounding box intersects with; and for each of those, we recursively check the appropriate octants of those octants, etc. until we get to the leaves of the tree, and then we do the normal point-in-bounding-box, then point-in-sphere tests.

Comment: Restructuring nList as a tree seems like the best way to go. This was very helpful.

Comment: +1 for lifting invariants out of inner loop.  Surprisingly, this performance optimization actually makes the algorithm *easier* to read.

Comment: @Paul I've found this to be the case a lot of the time. So while it's disappointing in a sense that Python doesn't really do any bytecode optimization (although of course there are third-party utilties for that), it's actually kind of nice to get this incentive to keep things clean.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you could save all that by:

```
filteredList = [int(node['num']) for sphere in sList \
    for node in nList if findRadius(sphere,node)<=sphere['radius']]
```

If the distance from a point to a sphere's globe is less than the sphere's radius, then I guess we can say it is in the sphere, right?

I assume findRadius is defined like:

```
def findRadius(sphere,node):
    return ((node['x']-sphere['x'])**2 + \
            (node['y']-sphere['y'])**2 + \
            (node['z']-sphere['z'])**2)**.5
```

Comment: The intent is to do a bounding box test first, and then do the radius test only if the bounding box test passes, because exponentiation is more computation-intensive than adding and subtracting. However, that work could just as easily be moved into `findRadius` (renamed appropriately - perhaps `isWithin`?); and it's dubious whether this is a net win when Python is imposing huge amounts of overhead just to manipulate the dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

(AFAICT, the following solution is algorithmically faster than any other answer posted so far: approximately O(*N* log *N*) vs O(N²). Caveat: this assumes that you don't have massive amounts of overlap between bounding boxes.)

If you are allowed to pre-compute an index structure:

1. Push all the min/max x values into a set and sort them, thus creating a list of vertical regions spanning the x-axis. Associate each region with the set of bounding boxes that contain it.
2. Repeat this procedure for min/max y values, to create a list of horizontal regions, and associate each region with the set of bounding boxes it contains.
3. For each point being tested:

   - Use a binary chop to find the horizontal region that contains the point's x coordinate. What you really want, though, is the set of bounding boxes associated with the region.
   - Likewise, find the set of bounding boxes associated with the y coordinate.
   - Find the intersection of these two sets.
4. Test the bounding boxes in this residue set using Pythagoras.